# Facebook social plugin on android

Tags: android, facebook-social-plugins

I would like to integrate Facebook's comment social plugin
( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ to comment on url) into my android application. 
I tried to use webview (use this answer [Android unable to implement facebook comment in a webview due to default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577312/android-unable-to-implement-facebook-comment-in-a-webview-due-to-default-browser) ) and it's work, but hard to customize, for example: I want to have a bigger Textbox for user to type the comment. My question is: "is there any solution to integrate something like "Facebook's comment social plugin" into android application by facebook sdk, java code,...  to comment on url?

Thanks & best regards

Comment: Did you find the solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have some URL page where you've  embedded your facebook social plugin with comments and you want  to parse this and display as you want. If I'm right, then unfortunately I haven't found easy solution via triggering appropriated methods from Facebook SDK. You have to use Graph API.

First of all we need to take a look into docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/comments

Here there is a example of call

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/{object-id}/comments",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

For getting **{object_id}** you need to send similar call to the Graph API, but for retrieving id:

```
  GET->  ?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt2015381%2F
```

And you will receive response which looks like

```
    {
  "og_object": {
    "id": "10150298925420108", 
    "description": "Directed by James Gunn.  With Chris Pratt, Vin Diesel, Bradley Cooper, Zoe Saldana. A group of intergalactic criminals are forced to work together to stop a fanatical warrior from taking control of the universe.", 
    "title": "Guardians of the Galaxy (2014)", 
    "type": "video.movie", 
    "updated_time": "2015-05-15T14:52:46+0000", 
    "url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/"
  }, 
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 4, 
    "share_count": 91073
  }, 
  "id": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/"
}
```

10150298925420108 is our **object_id**

So next query looks like `GET -> 10150298925420108/comments`
and response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10150298925420108_10152457293990108", 
      "can_remove": false, 
      "created_time": "2014-10-28T18:12:15+0000", 
      "from": {
        "id": "1513986108857171", 
        "name": "ซอโซ่ สระอา ยอยัก"
      }, 
      "like_count": 2, 
      "message": "สนุกมากค่ะ", 
      "user_likes": false
    }, 
    {
      "id": "10150298925420108_10152457392770108", 
      "can_remove": false, 
      "created_time": "2014-10-28T19:20:28+0000", 
      "from": {
        "id": "302917246580502", 
        "name": "สมชาย โกทันธ์"
      }, 
      "like_count": 0, 
      "message": "สองดาวครับ\n", 
      "user_likes": false
    }, 
    {
      "id": "10150298925420108_10152461977130108", 
      "can_remove": false, 
      "created_time": "2014-10-31T11:57:10+0000", 
      "from": {
        "id": "472810482857795", 
        "name": "Surat Thaenphet"
      }, 
      "like_count": 0, 
      "message": "แต่ละเรื่องที่ลง สนุกมาก แต่ดูไม่จบ ดูสักพัก ก็ eror  ไม่รุ้เป็นเพราะอะไร", 
      "user_likes": false
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "Mw==", 
      "after": "MQ=="
    }
  }
}
```

To test all this requests and response before doing it in Android app - use Graph API explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: This is BY FAR one of the best approaches I've found to have full control of the Graph API when trying to perform a comment in a native app. Although you should update a little bit the answer to the latest changes. THANK YOU.