# How to implement facebook comment plugin in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

How to implement Facebook comments plugin in Android,  which allows users to post comments to their wall as shown in the image given below ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CVFv.png]

Comment: That plugin is available for web only.

Comment: Can i create that plugin in a html file and load it on webview in android ? am searching for something like that..  @CBroe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570094/facebook-social-plugin-on-android please look this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this is not  what you looking for but i found few ideas that you could start rolling from like there is a Graph API  [Facebook social plugin on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570094/facebook-social-plugin-on-android) or in a WebView [Android unable to implement facebook comment in a webview due to default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577312/android-unable-to-implement-facebook-comment-in-a-webview-due-to-default-browser)

Edit: Should work if you set proper domain and path that already has comments.
Haven't checked how it will if original path doesn't have comments

```
package com.example.ff;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// changeable public variables 
    public static String APP_KEY = "You're app key";
    public static String BASE_DOMAIN = "http://www.9gag.com";
    public static String PATH_URL = "/tv/p/anNBpr";

    private WebView webView;
    private MainActivity context;



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cm.removeAllCookie();
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_login);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(BASE_DOMAIN, 
                "<html><head></head><body><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = \"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="+APP_KEY+ "\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\""
        +BASE_DOMAIN+PATH_URL+"\" data-width=\"470\"></div> </body></html>", "text/html", null, null);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientActivity());
    }
    public class WebViewClientActivity extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            System.out.println("onPageStarted: " + url);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
            System.out.println("onPageFinished: " + url);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @noobie artist  .  But am not looking for that. I want comment plugin exactly like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584176/failed-to-render-facebook-comments-on-android-webview-via-local-html#autocomment31184887

Comment: @AmalDevSI use the same thing as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108610/facebook-comment-box-in-android they are using WebView in android

Comment: But when i use that facebook.html file, an error occur as shown in below.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

Can u solve this ? @noobie artist

Comment: Thank u very much @noobie artist. The code is working great. :)

Comment: @AmalDevSI What should be pass in `PATH_URL` here ? can you please suggest me.

Comment: Placing the APP_KEY in your android aplication is the worst thing you can do

Comment: How can we do auto refresh of the comments?