# Facebook social plugin in Android application like 9gag

Tags: android, html, webview, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to implement facebook social plugin in webview like official android 9gag app has in comments.

My html which i am loading into webview looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
      appId      : '$APP_ID$',                      // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '$DOMAIN$/channel.php',            // Channel file for x-domain comms
      cookie       : true,
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });


// Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) { return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.async=true; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 
</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="$FB_SOCIAL_URL$" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i load this into webview nothing happened. When i use it on desktop nothing happen either. Only blank screen is shown. I also tried to implement settings for webview from this answer [Android unable to implement facebook comment in a webview due to default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655297/1478296) bud it didnt change nothing. I dont want to load all url with that facebook plugin but only that plugin itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the social part out and use facebook's android sdk for it. Chances are the users do not use mobile browsers for facebook. If you use fb android sdk, the experience is much better.

One thing if you still want to do it this way: you're missing the closing bracket for

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
```

Comment: I consider using facebook graph api and implement that discussion myself. Thanks anyway.. and that missing bracket unfortunately did not helped.