# What is the URL called when a user clicks a Like button?

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-like

I'm trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108088/android-webview-for-facebook-like-button) solution to get around the blank page in Android's WebView that is generated after a user logs into their FB account, upon clicking a like button, and it *works, except that when they're done logging in, I want to actually fulfill their LIKE request, rather than just re-offer them the like button and have them tap it again.

In the solution above they are referring to a getFacebookLikeUrl() method that no one details, but which is the key to the whole business of actually LIKEing something.

I'm hoping someone can chime in with what Facebook actually wants me to send, they obfuscate the call within the button so much that I'm having a really hard time figuring out what they're actually sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot actually "fulfill" Like behavior on behalf of the user.

BTW, `getFacebookLikeUrl()` is present in other question here ([How to handle facebook like with confirm in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485850/how-to-handle-facebook-like-with-confirm-in-android-webview)) but it's just a link to Like Button that user will need to click.

Comment: but the user has already clicked it! On the web, once the user has clicked a like button and has gone through the login, they're not required to click it again... *something is passed along to Facebook to fulfill their request, from just the initial click, right? Is there no way to just complete this transaction for them?

Comment: Yes and no ;) User clicked log-in button that just looked alike to Like Button.

Comment: umm... ok... and? I'm sorry, but I'm not following you. I'm not interfering with any native process... why does the WebView path not register the LIKE in the same way that a non WebView path does? Whatever the underlying mechanism is, what's being done differently?

Comment: actually, on second thought, you're absolutely right... it doesn't pass anything along and on line people have to re-like something after having logged in... I'm a putz. Thanks very much :)