# WebView social login

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a `WebView` to load my company's website.  Everything works fine until right after the user signs in using their facebook or googleplus accounts.  On the default android browser or any android browser, the sign in process creates a new tab letting the user sign in and afterward automatically closes the tab and redirects to the previous tab with the users content, it works as it should. However, when I disable cookies, it stops working.

After the user signs in using my WebView, it doesn't redirect to the original url.  If I press back, the OAuth data isn't passed back to the WebView.  This is what LogCat shows me:

```
05-17 19:39:24.615: E/Web Console(31990): Unable to post message to http://mycomp.website.com Recipient has origin https://authentication_endpoint
```

I'm not sure if this is because I'm not posting the OAuth data back to mycomp.website.com - and if it is I'm not sure how to fix this.  I know I need to handle cookies somehow, but I'm not sure how to implement a `CookieManager`. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this question is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485850/how-to-handle-facebook-like-with-confirm-in-android-webview