# WebViewClient will not open page handled in shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I'm using webview to show transaction process (payment by creditCard). If I use webView.load(given URL) it is working and it will redirect me to bank page in my browser from my app.

But I need to track if the payment is successful (it will redirect me to specific URL) and sent data back to the server.

I used webViewClient, but as I use the client, it will not redirect me to a browser page, it will stay at "processing data" screen inside the app for eternity. Even if I add only view.loadurl(URL) and return true inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading, it will do the same thing. There are 4-5 redirects till the final result. StartURL(add creditCardInfo) - Redirect to validation - redirect to payment confirmation - redirect to specific URL which returns data(if branch)

```
class PurchaseWebView: AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var purchaseWebView: WebView
private val api: API = API.getInstance(this)
private val webViewActivity = this

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.purchase_web_view_layout)

    purchaseWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    purchaseWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            createLog("WebView Loading url... ", url)
            if (url.startsWith("purchase.complete.url.com", 0)){
                api.purchaseCreditCardResult(url, webViewActivity, object: IPurchaseCallback{
                    override fun onError(errorJSON: JSONObject) {
                        createLog("WebView Error ", errorJSON.toString())
                    }

                    override fun onSuccess(purchaseJSON: JSONObject?) {
                        createLog("WebView Success ", "Finishing Activity")
                    }
                })
                return false
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    purchaseWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
            if (request.url.toString().startsWith("purchase.complete.url.com", 0)){

                api.purchaseCreditCardResult(request.url.toString(), webViewActivity, object: IPurchaseCallback{
                    override fun onError(errorJSON: JSONObject) {
                        createLog("WebView Error ", errorJSON.toString())
                    }

                    override fun onSuccess(purchaseJSON: JSONObject?) {
                        createLog("WebView Success ", "Finishing Activity")
                    }
                })
                return false
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    purchaseWebView.loadUrl(intent.extras.getString("purchaseURL"))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in this particular call `view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())`
When you're overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` you should return only `true` or `false`, which means - allow or forbid loading of passed url. But when you're returning `true` and also calls `loadUrl` you're trying to load same url twice. Remove the `loadUrl` command and just return `true`.

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
    view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())   // Why?
    return true
}
```

Comment: It did not help. I've used alot of tutorials and everybody used it like this. For example here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-WebView

Comment: Its still inside my app (i will get first URL from server as an response for purchase). First URL will redirect me (inside app) to fill credit card info. As I confirm those data, it will send data somewhere (its bank API). As I wait for confirmation there is loading circle. After that it will open default browser and redirect me to another page. This is how it works without WebViewClient. As I use WebViewClient I'm stuck at data confirmation page and that loading circle is there permanently. It looks like that it will refuse to open browser.

Comment: @martin1337, could it be cause `WebView` tries to open url in a separate window? (check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49793597/3569545).