# In Android Webview window open work just one time

Tags: android, laravel, webview, kotlin

My Website(use laravel) call window.open method on this code

```
window.open('My_URL','_blank');
```

and my Android Webview open new window on dialog. code is

```
override fun onCreateWindow(view:WebView, isDialog:Boolean,
    isUserGesture:Boolean, resultMsg:Message):Boolean {

    // set dialog webview
    val dialog = Dialog(context)
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)

    val newWebView = dialog.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.WebView)

    newWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    newWebView.loadUrl(view?.url)

    // open dialog full screen
    val window = dialog.window
    val wlp : WindowManager.LayoutParams = window.attributes
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    wlp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND
    window.attributes = wlp
    dialog.window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    dialog.show()
    (resultMsg.obj as WebView.WebViewTransport).setWebView(newWebView)
    resultMsg.sendToTarget()

    newWebView.setWebViewClient(object: WebViewClient() {

    })

    newWebView.setWebChromeClient(object:WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onCloseWindow(window:WebView) {
            dialog.dismiss()
            window.destroy()
            newWebView.destroy()
            //webview.removeView(newWebView)
        }
    })

    return true
}
```

it was work successful just one time.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will help you or not, but as far as I know the android application should provide handling of opening and closing window requests from `javascript`. I mean it does work out of the box, but very often not how it is expected/needed.

It is possible to show separate web `window` as a dialog, but as I know dialogs can't stack and appear on top of each other. Such approach fits case when you need to open (and then close) only one separate `window`. Please read more about dialogs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425019/3569545).

What I suggest is to show separate `WebView` on every `window.open()` request. Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49793597/3569545), where similar solution was solved. In your case (where any amount of opened windows possible) you can use a `LinkedList` of `WebView`s, pushing new one on `window.open()` and popping top ones on `window.close`.